# How to group the objects in an array so that they are not the same objects according to certain conditions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object array. I will create groups according to certain conditions and then set in node-cache.

My conditions are:

First group will be: <=300, Second group will be: <= 600,Last group will be : <= 900.

when grouping, even if a data satisfies all conditions, it will only be in the first group.

For Example:

```
array :[{no:1,price:500},{No:2,price:400},{No:3,price:300},{No:4,price:200},{No:5,price:600},{No:6,price:700},{No:7,price:800},{No:8,price:900}]
```

Result:

```
firsGroup :[{No:3,price:300},{No:4,price:200}];
secondGroup :[{no:1,price:500},{No:2,price:400},{No:5,price:600]
lastGroup :[{No:6,price:700},{No:7,price:800},{No:8,price:900}]
```

Note : We will not remove item in array when we groupping.

Comment: [Show us what you've tried please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). SO is not a programming service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a formula to get the right array from a given price:

```js
let array = [{no:1,price:500},{no:2,price:400},{no:3,price:300},{no:4,price:200},{no:5,price:600},{no:6,price:700},{no:7,price:800},{no:8,price:900}];

let result = [[], [], []];
for (let obj of array) {
    let cat = Math.floor((obj.price - 1) / 300);
    result[cat].push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```

If the formula `(price - 1) / 300` would not be appropriate, you can just use a ternary expression to evaluate to the right index value:

```js
let array = [{no:1,price:500},{no:2,price:400},{no:3,price:300},{no:4,price:200},{no:5,price:600},{no:6,price:700},{no:7,price:800},{no:8,price:900}];

let result = [[], [], []];
for (let obj of array) {
    let cat = obj.price <= 300 ? 0
            : obj.price <= 600 ? 1
            : 2
    result[cat].push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```